# Why is the first element only posted in this code?

Tags: java, android

I want to `post` database records to a webserver :

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllNewOrUpdatedParcelles() {
        ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
        String enreg, quartier_id = getCommune().getQuartierId();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + T_PARCELLE + " WHERE bien_code != 0 AND ( updated = 'true' OR new_enreg = 'true')";
        Cursor c = bd.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                enreg = "data_parcelle=yes";
                enreg += "&bien_code="+c.getString(0);
                enreg += "&decoup_terri_code="+c.getString(1);
                enreg += "&dec_decoup_terri_code="+c.getString(2);
                enreg += "&bien_ident="+c.getString(3);
                enreg += "&parcel_denomination="+c.getString(4);
                enreg += "&parcel_porte_ppale="+c.getString(5);
                enreg += "&parcel_porte_second="+c.getString(6);
                enreg += "&parcel_superfi_totale="+c.getString(7);
                enreg += "&parcel_superf_batie="+c.getString(8);
                enreg += "&parcel_superf_non_batie="+c.getString(9);
                enreg += "&parcel_superf_plani="+c.getString(10);
                enreg += "&quartier_code="+quartier_id;
                enreg += "&parcel_date_deb_construct="+c.getString(12);
                enreg += "&parcel_date_fin_construct="+c.getString(13);
                if (c.getString(14).equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
                    enreg += "&nouvel_enreg=yes";
                else
                    enreg += "&nouvel_enreg=no";
                ret.add(enreg);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

The http post :

```
private void postData(String p_url) {

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            OutputStreamWriter writer = null;

            try {

                ArrayList<String> ret = db.getAllNewOrUpdatedParcelles();
                if (ret.size() > 0) {

                    for (String enreg : ret) {
                        URL url = new URL(p_url);
                        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                        urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
                        writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                        writer.write(enreg);
                        writer.flush();
                        writer.close();
                        urlConnection.disconnect();
                    }

                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                error = true;
                err = contextInsideDialogue.getResources().getString(R.string.errBadUrl);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                error = true;
                err = contextInsideDialogue.getResources().getString(R.string.errAccessError);
            } finally {
                if (writer != null) { try { writer.close(); } catch (IOException e) {} }
                if (urlConnection != null) { urlConnection.disconnect(); }
            }

        }
```

**UPDATE :**

At the server side ( PHP ) I treat the post data like this :

```
$db = new DbConn() ;

        $trace = new trace($db->getInstance(), T_TRACE_ACCES);

        /*
         * 
         * traitement des parcelles
         * 
         */

        if (isset($_POST['data_parcelle'])) {

            require_once RP_MODELS.'parcelle.class.php';
            require_once RP_MODELS.'decoupage_territoire.class.php';

            $parcelle = new parcelle($db->getInstance(), T_PARCELLE);

            $decoupage_territoire = new decoupage_territoire($db->getInstance(), T_DECOUPAGE_TERRITOIRE);

            $critereDecoup["decoup_terri_code"] = $_POST['dec_decoup_terri_code'];

            $rue = $decoupage_territoire->lire($critereDecoup);

            $critereDecoup["decoup_terri_code"] = $_POST['quartier_code'];

            $quartier = $decoupage_territoire->lire($critereDecoup);

            $critereDecoup["decoup_terri_code"] = $quartier["dec_decoup_terri_code"];

            $commune = $decoupage_territoire->lire($critereDecoup);

            $_POST['parcel_adresse'] = $_POST['parcel_porte_ppale'] . ", " . $rue["decoup_terri_nom"] . " - " . $quartier["decoup_terri_nom"] . " - " . $commune["decoup_terri_nom"];

            $_POST['parcel_date_deb_construct'] = convertDateFormat5($_POST['parcel_date_deb_construct']);
            $_POST['parcel_date_fin_construct'] = convertDateFormat5($_POST['parcel_date_fin_construct']);

            if ($_POST['nouvel_enreg'] == 'yes') {

                require_once RP_MODELS.'bien.class.php';

                $bien = new bien($db->getInstance(), T_BIEN);

                $_POST['bien_code_sig'] = $_POST['bien_ident'];
                $bien->ajouter($_POST);
                $bien_code = $bien->lireDernierId();

                $_POST['bien_code'] = $bien_code;

                $parcelle->ajouter($_POST);

                $traceContent = "Ajout par mobile : " . $_POST["bien_code"] . " / " . $_POST["parcel_denomination"];

            }
            else {

                $parcelle->modifier($_POST, array("bien_code"));

                $traceContent = "Modification par mobile : " . $_POST["bien_code"] . " / " . $_POST["parcel_denomination"];

            }

            $critereTrace = array();

            $critereTrace["trc_action"]  = $traceContent;

            $trace->ajouter($critereTrace);

        }
```

The problem is that the first record is only posted ! So how to make all records to be posted ?

Comment: Does it make any error or just doesn't make new connection?

Comment: do you have to send each piece of data within a single http-connection? now it's totally ineffective...

Comment: So is the size of `ret.size()` 1? As an aside, you shouldn't close and open connections in your loop. Take them outside and reuse the connection where possible but that's unrelated to your question.

Comment: Are you sure there should be many records in your query?

Comment: I think I know what's going on. Using the built in API, you need to consume the response before the connection is "released" and ready to be reused. Add these after your writer.close() and before your disconnect: `InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      String line;
      StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
      while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
      }`

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) { 
  do {
    ...
  }while (c.moveToNext());
```

use simple:

```
while(c.moveToNext()) {
  ...
}
```

UPDATE

For data sending I'd recommend using `HttpClient` implementaion, like [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html). It provides handy methods for building the request up:

```
HttpClient httpClient =  AndroidHttpClient.newInstance( "Android", this );

public List<List<NameValuePair>> getAllNewOrUpdatedParcelles() {
    List<List<NameValuePair>> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    String enreg, quartier_id = getCommune().getQuartierId();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + T_PARCELLE + " WHERE bien_code != 0 AND ( updated = 'true' OR new_enreg = 'true')";
    Cursor c = bd.rawQuery(query, null);
    try{
      while( c.moveToNext() ){
        List<NameValuePair> curr = new ArrayList<>();
        curr.add( new BasicNameValuePair( "data_parcelle", "yes" ) );
        curr.add( new BasicNameValuePair( "bien_code", c.getString(0) ) ); 
        // and so on
        ret.add( curr );
      }
    }finally{ c.close(); }
    return ret;
}

private void postData(String p_url) {
  for( List<NameValuePair> params : getAllNewOrUpdatedParcelles() ){
    try{
      HttpPost post = new HttpPost( p_url );
      httppost.setEntity( new UrlEncodedFormEntity( params, HTTP.UTF_8 ) );
      HttpResponse hr = httpClient.execute( httppost );
      Log.i( TAG, "result status = " + hr.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() );
    }catch( IOException e ){
      Log.i( TAG, "exception", e );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `c.moveToFirst()` should be called, so that was right.

Comment: no, right after init, the `c.moveToNext()` is just fine

Comment: `c.moveToFirst()` is needed, if you have already iterated through the cursor

Comment: then your problem is that either the query returns a single record (that others have noted already), or your connection breaks down. Add some logging `Log.i( TAG, c.getCount() )` and `Log.i( TAG, ret.size() )` to check the 1st possible reason.

Comment: `ret.size()` is 2 , but I think I don't know how to work with the connection and the OutputStreamWriter , so how to use them correctly ?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + O (in Eclipse) should resolve your import problems

Comment: what do you see in the logcat for `Log.i( TAG, "result status = " + hr.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() );`? add also `Log.i( TAG, "params = " + params );` and see what it gives

Comment: then add some `Toast`s. and definitely check server logs

Comment: how will I `toast` the `params` variable ?

Comment: that would be brutally off-topic